How to communicate between server components and WASM components
Let's say I have a WASM component in my .Client project called "Counter", and I embed it on a server page. How do communicate with the component? I want to do something like this:
<Counter @ref=_counter></Counter>

@code {
    Counter _counter;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _counter.MethodCall();

        base.OnInitialized();
    }
}


But if i do, i get this exception, because of the @ref=_counter

System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type
'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Endpoints.SSRRenderModeBoundary' to
type 'Blazor9Test.Client.Pages.Counter'.'


Why would you want to do this?  What's the use case?
